# jQuery validation error (element is undefined)

Tags: jquery, validation

I keep getting the error

> element is undefined var validator = $.data(element.form, 'validator'); on line 803 of jquery.validate.js

and cannot for the life of me figure out why. I have added a form wizard to this form. When I remove it, it works fine. If I leave the form wizard and remove validation, it works fine. But the two can't seem to work together. I've used them in the past and the set up is exactly the same.

Form is here: http://www.dirtybirddesignlab.com/purchaseForm.php

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You should use a debugger like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), put a breakpoint in the problematic function, and step through line-by-line.

Comment: @Matt Bell -I'm using firebug, how do I put a breakpoint in?

Comment: Open the `Script` tab, use the dropdown to select the right JS file, and double-click the left margin (where the line numbers are) at the line you want to insert the breakpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the cause of your problem starts at line `67` in file `formToWizard.js`, the exact line is `var xy = element.validate().element($(this));`

Comment: I was attempting to find you a fix, but it looks like you are working on it so I can't get consistent response to be able to client side debug it for you

Comment: @K Ivanov, form is back, pls disregard any styling issues

Comment: the validation fails when it reaches the validation of: <p><input type="checkbox">I wish to participate in the CME Group Globex Exchange Fee Waiver program. Your account will stream delayed CMD Globex data until you <a href="cme-validation.php" target="_blank">validate your waiver program eligibility</a> at which time, real time CME Globex data will be available within a 24 hour period</p>, try giving it id

Comment: @K Ivanov - man thank you. how did you trace to that? really very much appreciated man. thank you.

Comment: I find it easier to use IE9 and its Developer Tools (F12) for client debugging, but Firebug does the same thing on Firefox

Comment: you also have to give it class="valid", or just exclude from validation if that is easier